# VSCode - cursor problem when expanding brackets

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I create a new class and brackets for it and hit enter to expand it this is how it worked before (cursor on its own line):

```
.class {
  //cursor here
}
```

now for some reason it work like this (cursor on the same line as closing bracket):

```
.class {
//cursor here}
```

Anyone knows what setting did I messed up and how to fix it so it works as before? Tried disabling all extensions but the problem is still there.

Comment: what language is this? CSS? What language mode is your editor tab set to? (check the indicator at the bottom right).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Somehow I managed to set this line

```
"editor.language.brackets": []
```

in my settings.json file